# How does StackExchange API implements the common wrapper object?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, rest, asp.net-web-api, servicestack, stackexchange-api

How do they do this http://api.stackexchange.com/docs/wrapper ? I am aware that these are ServiceStack driven APIs but some code samples would be nice.

I want to implement something similar but with ASP.NET Web API.

Still if someone can provide StackExchange code implemented with ServiceStack, for example and reference only, that would work too.

Comment: Only StackOverflow Careers backoffice API's are implemented with ServiceStack. StackOverflow API's use vanilla ASP.NET MVC.

Comment: well then, still hopefully someone responds how they implemented the wrapper functionality, what best practices are to follow when doing that, how they handle paging, qouta etc.

Comment: May I want you place what we have and what we want? It seems amazing question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can gain some understanding of internal structure by exploring [StacMan](https://github.com/StackExchange/StacMan) client library. [Wrapper](https://github.com/StackExchange/StacMan/blob/master/StacMan/Codegen/Wrapper.cs) and [StacManResponse](https://github.com/StackExchange/StacMan/blob/master/StacMan/StacManResponse.cs) classes in particular. 
**Update:**
There are also series of articles from Kevin Montrose about StackExchange API evolution and nuances: [Stack Exchange API V2.0: Consistency](http://kevinmontrose.com/2012/02/16/stack-exchange-api-v2-0-consistency/), [History Of The Stack Exchange API, Mistakes](http://kevinmontrose.com/2011/08/14/history-of-the-stack-exchange-api-mistakes/) for example.
[StackExchange performance page](https://stackexchange.com/performance) contains information about programming stack used, which is: C# + ASP.net MVC, Dapper ORM, StackExchange.Redis, DotNetOpenAuth, MiniProfiler, Jil. And [The Architecture of Stack Overflow video](https://youtu.be/rkVvxgdY9F8?t=11m19s) contains information about some of SO software development principles.

Comment: Leonid, this may be useful, but does not constitute an answer. Links are good for comments. An answer can contain a link but should also include code samples and explanation. If you want to create an answer, study the links and add relevant pseudo code.